# Measure on $([0,1], \mathcal{P}([0,1]))$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm working on measures and I need to prove the following:

There exists no measure on $([0,1]\mathcal{P}([0,1]))$ such that

- $\mu([0,1]) = 1$
- $\mu(A) \in \{0,1\}$ for any $A \subseteq[0,1]$
- $\mu(F) = 0$ for any $F \subseteq[0,1]$ finite

I understand why this is so and to some extent how to prove it:

1) We suppose there is such a measure.

2) We split the interval in two disjoint intervals and use the additivity of measures on disjoint sets to show that one of the subintervals has measure 1 and the other one 0.

3) We do it recursively and we obtain a sequence of intervals of measure 1 that converges to a singleton of measure 1.

4) This is a contradiction since the measure of finite sets is 0.

I'm not sure how to mathematically write step 3) in a rigorous way. Could anyone please help me? I'm pretty sure this is a standard exercise for an undergraduate course on Lebesgue theory but I didn't manage to find a proof online. If there has already been such a post, a redirection would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you need a further assumption that the measure is regular or something? More precisely you need that $\mu(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mu(A_n)$ for every decreasing sequence of sets $A_n$.

Comment: @Yanko that's just true for all measures, assuming the measure of the whole space is finite, which is the case here.

Comment: Actually, my question is more how to define in a rigorous way the interval $A_n$?

Comment: You define $A_n$ recursively. You need words for that.

Comment: Okay, so there is no "math-symbols only" definition for it?

Comment: Something like this: For every subinterval $I$ of $[0,1]$ let $\ell(I)$ and $u(I)$ denote its lower and upper halves, defined as... Then, given $A_n$, let $A_{n+1}=\ell(A_n)$ if $\mu(\ell(A_n))=1$ and $A_{n+1}=u(A_n)$ otherwise. Then... (etc.)

Comment: @mathworker21 now I see you're right thanks.

Comment: @jffi Technically you can write it straightforward but you will have $2^n$ cases each with $2^{n-1}$ conditions. Say for $A_1$ you can write $$A_1 = \begin{cases} \displaystyle
  [0,\frac{1}{2}] &\mu([0,\frac{1}{2}])=1 \\
   [\frac{1}{2},1] & \mu([0,\frac{1}{2}])=0 \\
\end{cases}$$ and for $A_2$ you will have $4$ cases for $[0,\frac{1}{4}],[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}],[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}],[\frac{3}{4},1]$ each with two conditions, say you get $[0,\frac{1}{4}]$ only if both $[0,\frac{1}{4}]$ and $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ of measure $1$. but this is not elegant at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define the sets $A_n$ recursively as follows:

Let $A_0=[0,1]$. Given an interval $I=[a,b]$ let $f(I):=[a,\frac{a+b}{2}]$ and $g(I):= [\frac{a+b}{2},b]$ we clearly have that $I=f(I)\bigcup g(I)$ (also the union is disjoint up to measure zero).

Assuming we constructed $A_n$ such that $\mu(A_n)=1$, we construct $A_{n+1}$ as follows:

Look at $f(A_n),g(A_n)$, then we have that $A_n=f(A_n)\cup g(A_n)$ is of measure $1$. Therefore $\mu(f(A_n))+\mu(g(A_n))=1$ and so either $f(A_n)$ or $g(A_n)$ is of measure $1$. Let $A_{n+1}$ be this interval (the one of measure $1$).

We obtain a sequence of intervals $A_n$ such that $\mu(A_n)=1$. Moreover $A_{n+1}$ is either $f(A_n)$ or $g(A_n)$ and so it's length is half the length of $A_n$.